# How to scroll to a particular position in recyclerview inside scrollview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-nestedscrollview, linearlayoutmanager

I have searched a lot regarding my query and none of them was useful. I have a recyclerview and some static data inside a scroll view which is inside a root parentlayout as show below.

I have set -

```
scrollview.scrollto(0,0);
```

because everytime i open the activity it jumps to the recyclerview firstitem and it skips out the static data above the recyclerview.

```
recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); 
recyclerview.setfocusable(false);
```

for smoothscroll.

the problem is with-

```
layoutmanager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos,0);
```

it is not working. I have set the aboveline after setting adapter to recyclerview. Also tried with NestedScrollView but in vain.

although I have used

```
layoutmanager.scrollToPosition(pos);
```

> For those who skip the code, i have set match_parent to ScrollView and
>   fillviewport to true.

Here is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottomsheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.inkdrops.khaalijeb.BrandCouponActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/inclusionviewgroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <static data/>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollviewmain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/one"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_above="@+id/donelayout">


            <staticdata/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dealstext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/card1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="Deals &amp; Coupons"
                    android:textColor="#444444" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerlayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/dealstext"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorbackground">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/coupon_rec_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/colorbackground"
                        android:visibility="visible"/>


                </RelativeLayout>

                <statisdata>


            </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        include layout="@layout/activity_coupons"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post some of your android code as well? Are you sure you're referencing the right `layoutManager`? Not the `RecyclerView`'s but the `ScrollView`'s right?

Comment: You want to retain scroll postion on rotation or just programmatically  want to scroll to certain position?

Comment: paste your adapter and related activity/fragment code as well @akshay_shahane.

Answer (score 36):

Need to scroll `ScrollView` by getting top position of `RecyclerView`'s child :

```
float y = recyclerView.getY() + recyclerView.getChildAt(selectedPosition).getY();    
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, (int) y);
```

Comment: Is X zero speed?

Comment: @danny117 No. [It is position on scroll x-axis, horizontal scroll value](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Comment: (without looking) I was hoping it would be similar to jquery that has speed and y on scrollto method.

Comment: In my case, the scrollView is moving, but it doesn't go to the specified adapter position. Any ideas pls?

Comment: @msrowley debug position you are scrolling to

Comment: @msrowley Add Y position of RecyclerView to the child's Y position if your RecyclerView isn't the first element in the XML file.

Comment: What if I want not only top but that whole particular item to be visible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use scroll view method to reach your desired locations as:

```
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(int x, int y);
```

Answer (score -2):

### Step 1: Add this line for selecting that position in the recyclerview

```
  adaptercat.setSelectedItem(Integer.parseInt(dealtypeid));
```

### Step 2: Once check below constructor by getting current position

```
  public CatgerotyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist,String selectedPosition) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = arraylist;
        resultp = new HashMap<>();
        currentItemPos=Integer.parseInt(selectedPosition)-1;
    }
```

### Step 3: And this function also in adapter

```
  public void setCurrentItem(int item)
    {
        this.currentItemPos = item;
    }
```

### Last step 4. Add this function outside adapter in your class

```
 private void onPagerItemClick2(Integer tag)
{
    adaptercat.setCurrentItem(tag);
    catsp.setAdapter(adaptercat);
}
```

### Pust this line in your listview item click listner

```
  ((ClassName) context).onPagerItemClick2(position);
```

### That position will be selected when will you open listview ..

Answer (score -3):

Use this method [scrollToPosition (int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollToPosition(int)) this is work for me. hope this will help you.

```
        mMessagesRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messagesRecyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        mMessagesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mMessagesAdapter = new MessagesAdapter();
        mMessagesRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMessagesAdapter);

        mMessagesRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(your position);
```

**this is my layoutstructer**

[image]